# How to optimise/scale-proof this algorithm?

Tags: database, optimization

My website currently displays content in order of rank with a similar algorithm to this:
rank = points/age

The only problem is as there is more and more content added it won't be practical to generate a content rank for every piece of content on every page request.
We can't put the rank in the database because it changes each second.

Anyone have any ideas on how to go about optimizing this?

In pseudo code:

```
content_items = getContentFromDb();
foreach( content_items -> item ){
    calRank(item);
}
sort(content_items);
foreach( content_items -> item ){
    display(item);
}
```

Comment: @sehe Sorry, I've changed the title.

Comment: @sehe Weird. It's changed on mine.
I've added some pseudo code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go, the way you now show the problem, it is quite obvious that is mainly a matter of caching the ranking information.

If you want to share the caclulated rankings across a farm, I suggest a simple key/value database. There are plenty of those around, but unfortunately I haven't used any of the in any serious capacity. I suggest you read up on NoSql and perhaps look at memcached, couchdb, mongodb.

However, for now, I'd just look at caching the rankings. Period. Optimize when necessary